# Disabling NSLogs from .a libs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've a lot of .a in my project from various libraries and some of the spam the console with
output.

Is there a way to disable all NSLogs from my build even my own?

Will these effect the final release build in anyway?

For example:

```
AD URL: http://ads.mp.mydas.mobi/getAd.php5?medialets=false&sdkapid=44300&auid=a83014b158258e5bda3ee3f3634eaa17b66d9fce&mmisdk=4.2.4-11.4.25.i&ua=iPhone%204.2.1&dv=4.2.1&dm=iPhone2,1&adtype=MMBannerAdTop&hswd=320&hsht=53&accelerometer=true&vendor=adwhirl&video=true&language=en&country=IE&cachedvideo=true
```

This gets output to the console. But searching in the project for text 'AD URL' finds nothing. Can I force these to be removed ignored somehow?

Comment: There's no trivial way to disable log statements from linked-in libraries; those are already compiled, and already link against Foundation's `NSLog` export. You'd have to somehow redirect that linkage, which is some varsity stuff.

Comment: Don’t these libraries have two versions: one for debug and one for release? If so, using the release version should get rid of `NSLog()s` — in an ideal world, anyway.

Comment: Did my answer work? I see it's checked off as such. A comment of explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: I wish Xcode had a linker option to achieve exactly this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSLog does indeed effect the performance of release builds. I recommend doing a global search and replace of all NSLog statements. That way, you can delete or at least comment out all logging statements.

For future reference, you can make your own loggig function that wraps NSLog, but checks for a compile time constant, which you would define.

**EDIT:**

It might be possible to override those NSLogs with a category. (I have no clue which class to make a category of, however.)

Comment: `NSLog` is a [function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJAAIA), not a method of a class. It can't be overridden that way. If the library is already compiled, then as quixoto said, it's tricky to get around it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Thanks, I moved it over to the question and pinged the OP.

Answer (score 0):

simple (but not the cleanest of approaches) approach is to declare some #define like

```
#if defined(NO_LOGS)
    #define NSLog(xyz) 
#endif
```

which will supress all NSLog statements when you turn on NO_LOGS.

Comment: That will work for my NSLogs, but the real problem in the NSLogs from included libraries.